# Tableau Impala empty dates

Tags: impala, tableau-api

I've been creating tableau dashboards for a while now using the `ZN(Lookup(SUM(field), 0))` trick for a while now to pad empty dates with zeros.

However, when using the same trick with a live Impala connection to a Hadoop cluster, it seems that the output is no longer padded.

Does anyone know why it no longer works and what the potential solution would be?